# HTML box moves when using JQuery statements hide/fadetoggle

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to create a contact form which appears when you select the button on my website;

http://acewc.net23.net/

but you'll see as you press the down arrow the initial box surrounding the text 'Get a Quote now' moves down a good few pixels and I can't figure out how/why it does?!

The jquery code is very simple;

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            window.onload = function(){
                $('#contact-form').hide();
        };

            $("#dd").click(function(){
                $('#contact-form').fadeToggle(750);
            });

        });
    </script>
```

I've got quite a bit for the css files so don't want to post all that code, but do you think it'd be the box with the 'Get quote' text or my actual form that's causing it to move around?!

Thanks in advance people!

Comment: One initial suggestion: set #contact-form to hidden with CSS instead. The load twitch isn't very nice. Also, you probably don't need two .ready wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove (to prevent form to display while the page is loading)

```
 window.onload = function(){
                $('#contact-form').hide();
        };
```

And change/add to your css :

```
#contact-form {
  position: aboslute; /* Change relative to absolute */
  display: none; /* Add this to hide the form */
  top: 175px; /* Position in page */
  width: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's better to transition a wrapper div than a form itself. Try this:

```
<div id="contact-form-wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <form id="contact-form" action="/" method="post">
        ...
    </form>
</div>

$("#dd").on('click', function() {
    $('#contact-form-wrapper').fadeToggle(750);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with he answer above, I feel like absolute positioning of the element is not what you want.

I would remove the position absolute on right_section_title, and then on your form element you can either remove the "position: relative;" and "top: 46px;" (I think that looks fine), or you could change "top: 46px;" to position the form where you want.

```
 .right_section_title {
 font: 14pt "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 background-color: #a2d0ff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 vertical-align: middle;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 15px solid #a2d0ff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 height: 22px;
 width: 330px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px -2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
 box-shadow: 0px -2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
 }


 #contact-form {
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
 border: 1px;
 border-color: #a4a4a4;
 border-style: none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 background: #a2d0ff;
 padding-left: 5px;
 }
```

Also, on a side note, your jquery does not need the window on load, document ready handles that, you can change it to:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $('#contact-form').hide();


        $("#dd").click(function(){
            $('#contact-form').fadeToggle(750);
        });

    });
 </script>
```

Though if you decide to display none in the css, as suggested above, then you don't need to hide it at all. That would be best i think.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thanks for the alternative but it didn't really work. The twitch was still there?!

Comment: yikes... seemed to work for me in chrome. i did not try it any other browser. I just pulled it off in the element inspector just now, and by removing the position absolute from the right_section_title element, the twitch stopped.